# Lua table examples are not working for me

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-5.3

I'm trying code from lua.org and from my 4th edition Programming in Lua hardcopy, and as far as I've read all these table examples should work but 3 out of 4 don't, and I cant find anything the docs that says why. Some help on what I am missing appreciated. I assume some spec has changed as I already found out with table.getn() not being available anymore. My linux box has Lua 5.3.5

```
local t1={}
t1[1]="Foo"
t1[2]="Bar"
print("Size: "..#t1)
print("Works:"..table.concat(t1,'$$'))

local t2={}
t2[5]="Foo"
t2[40]="Bar"
print("Size: "..#t2)
print("Doesnt Work:"..table.concat(t2,'$$'))

local t3={}
t3["A"]="Foo"
t3["B"]="Bar"
print("Size: "..#t3)
print("Doesnt Work:"..table.concat(t3,'$$'))

local t4={}
t4.A="Foo"
t4.B="Bar"
print("Size: "..#t4)
print("Doesnt Work:"..table.concat(t4,'$$'))
```

Results

```
Size: 2
Works:Foo$$Bar
Size: 0
Doesnt Work:
Size: 0
Doesnt Work:
Size: 0
Doesnt Work:
```

Answer (score 4):

Please read [Lua Reference Manual: 3.4.7 The Length Operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7)

> The length operator applied on a table returns a border in that table.
> A border in a table t is any natural number that satisfies the
> following condition:
>
> ```
>  (border == 0 or t[border] ~= nil) and t[border + 1] == nil
> ```
>
> In words, a border is any (natural) index present in the table that is
> followed by an absent index (or zero, when index 1 is absent).
>
> A table with exactly one border is called a sequence. For instance,
> the table {10, 20, 30, 40, 50} is a sequence, as it has only one
> border (5). The table {10, 20, 30, nil, 50} has two borders (3 and 5),
> and therefore it is not a sequence. (The nil at index 4 is called a
> hole.) The table {nil, 20, 30, nil, nil, 60, nil} has three borders
> (0, 3, and 6) and three holes (at indices 1, 4, and 5), so it is not a
> sequence, too. The table {} is a sequence with border 0. Note that
> non-natural keys do not interfere with whether a table is a sequence.
>
> When t is a sequence, #t returns its only border, which corresponds to
> the intuitive notion of the length of the sequence. When t is not a
> sequence, #t can return any of its borders. (The exact one depends on
> details of the internal representation of the table, which in turn can
> depend on how the table was populated and the memory addresses of its
> non-numeric keys.)

Applied to your examples:

```
local t1={}
t1[1]="Foo"
t1[2]="Bar"
```

`t1` has only one boarder (2), because `t1[2] ~= nil and t1[2+1] == nil`.

`t1` has only 1 border -> `t1` is a squence -> `#t1` is the length of `t1`.

```
local t2={}
t2[5]="Foo"
t2[40]="Bar"
```

`t2` has 3 borders (0, 5, 40), because `boarder == 0 and t[0+1] == nil`, `t[5] ~= nil and t[5+1] == nil`, `t[40]~=nil and t[40+1]==nil`

`t2` has more than one borders-> `#t2` is any of its borders, not its length.

```
local t3={}
t3["A"]="Foo"
t3["B"]="Bar"
```

`t3` has 1 border (0), because `border == 0 and t3[0+1] == nil`, no more numeric keys so no more borders. `t3` has only one border -> `t3` is a sequence with length 0.

```
local t4={}
t4.A="Foo"
t4.B="Bar"
```

is the same as `t4` as `t.name` is syntactic sugar for `t["name"]`. Only works for valid Lua names!

`t1` is the only sequence among your examples and hence the only one `#` yields the number of element for.

If you are unsure if you have a sequence you should count the elements like so:

```
local n = 0
for _ in pairs(t) do
  n = n + 1
end
```

This is how you would print the boarders of a table `t`:

```
function printBorders(t)
  local borders = {}
  for k in pairs(t) do
    if  type(k) == "number" and
      t[k] ~= nil and t[k+1] == nil then
      table.insert(borders, k)
    end
  end
  if t[1] == nil then table.insert(borders, 0) end
  table.sort(borders)
  print(table.concat(borders, ", "))
end
```